# displaying validation message using Ajax.beginform in a partial

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am new in .NET mvc 5 environment.

> I have a view:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Accounts.WebHost.Models.SendUsernameReminderInputModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "SendUsernameReminder", null, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "validationList", LoadingElementId = "loader", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", OnFailure = "onFailure" }, new { @id = "validationForm", @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group hidden">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tenant, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "default" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}
<hr />

<div id="loader" class="alert" style="display:none">
    <img src="~/Content/img/ajax-loader.gif" />
</div>

@Html.Partial("_UsernameValidation")
```

> And a Partial view:

**_UsernameValidation.cshtml**

```
@model Accounts.WebHost.Models.SendUsernameReminderInputModel

<div id="validationList">
    <table>

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tenant)</td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

> this is my Controller:

**SendUsernameReminderController.cs**

```
using Accounts.Entities.Models;
using Accounts.WebHost.Models;
using BrockAllen.MembershipReboot;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Accounts.WebHost.Controllers
{
    public class SendUsernameReminderController : Controller
    {
        public readonly UserAccountService<MemberAccount> userAccountService;

        public SendUsernameReminderController(UserAccountService<MemberAccount> userAccountService)
        {
            this.userAccountService = userAccountService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string signin)
        {
            ViewBag.Signin = signin;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(SendUsernameReminderInputModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.userAccountService.SendUsernameReminder(model.Tenant, model.Email);
                    return RedirectToAction("Success", model);
                }
                catch (ValidationException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ValidationResult.ToString() == "The email address for this account is not yet verified.")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            userAccountService.ResetPassword(model.Tenant, model.Email);
                            return RedirectToAction("Unverified");
                        }
                        catch (ValidationException resetex)
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", resetex.Message);
                            ViewBag.Message = "resetex.Message";
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
                    return View();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Success(SendUsernameReminderInputModel model)
        {
            ViewBag.Subject = "Username Emailed";
            ViewBag.Message = "Your username was emailed at " + model.Email + ". If you don't receive this email within 24 hours, please check your junk mail folder or visit our Help pages to contact Customer Service for further assistance.";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Unverified()
        {
            ViewBag.Subject = "Email has not been verified";
            ViewBag.Message = "You will receive an email from us to confirm your email or cancel your registration. If you don't receive this email within 24 hours, please check your junk mail folder or visit our Help pages to contact Customer Service for further assistance.";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

> And this is my Model:

**SendUsernameReminderInputModel.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Accounts.WebHost.Models
{
    public class SendUsernameReminderInputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string Tenant
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

my aim is that when a user clicks the form submit button **only** the validation message will display below the form. unfortunately, **it outputs the whole Index.cshtml in the partial and the validation message at the bottom.**

If this is a bad approach please give me directions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try customEditorTemplate

Comment: why you are using partial view only for two fields..u can write that validationMessagefor code in your Index.cshtml then validation message will display with your textboxes.

Comment: @MukulSharma that was my original code structure. but the problem there is when I submit the form it outputs the whole Index.cshtml below the original textbox

Comment: Did you try using  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) instead of partial view ?

Comment: @RaviA. Yes, i tried using Html.ValidationMessageFor. but it outputs the validation message AND the form.

Comment: Can you add a image on how it looks now and what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

U need to pass `Model` like `View(model)` ; so that the View gets the model with those errors.
And u could also use `@Html.ValidationSummary` to display all the errors on a fly